# Elasticsearch: different queries on different fields in a single query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. I wonder how to use different queries on different fields in a single query. For example, match query on field 1 and field 2, term query on field 3.

Any info is really appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the Elasticsearch Bool Query:

> **Bool Query**
>
> A query that matches documents matching boolean combinations of other
>   queries. The bool query maps to Lucene BooleanQuery. It is built using
>   one or more boolean clauses, each clause with a typed occurrence.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

And the related Bool Filter:

> **Bool Filter**
>
> A filter that matches documents matching boolean combinations of other
>   queries. Similar in concept to Boolean query, except that the clauses
>   are other filters. Can be placed within queries that accept a filter.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html

Comment: John, thanks again for pointing me to the right direction. best.